# While loop VS. $sqlResult -> fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ;

Tags: php, mysqli, standards

Not exactly sure why but I've seen this come up a number of times today.

```
global $connection;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

$result = $connection->query($sql);

$rows = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $rows[] = $row;

}

return $rows;
```

Why not just use the built in function of **fetch_all**

```
global $connection;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

$result = $connection->query($sql);

return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Wouldn't this render the while loop unnecessary? 
Any advantages? 
Speed differences?

Comment: A) Developer is reading an old tutorial/book and that's how it shows to do it. B) That's all the developer knows. C) They like how it looks. D) The while version won't throw an error like a foreach ($rows  as $row) would if the developer didn't error check that a result was returned before looping on it ( seems like most don't ).  Could keep going...

Comment: B) - is definitely not acceptable. "Developer" should learn what he's got on his utility belt. And if you can keep going, do?

Comment: A while is only making a second copy of one record at a time, while foreach () holds the entire result set plus a copy of the (each) record, so memory footprint is smaller. Today this is rather negligible, but when working with large result sets it could make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could have been it was implemented before $mysqli came along, then $mysqli came along, along with the fetch_all functionality and the developer was lazy and saw that that would be the easiest way to update the code.

Answer (score 2):

some valid statements here already.. but just to add to it on the mysqli_fetch_all documentation it states (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php):

> As mysqli_fetch_all() returns all the rows as an array in a single
>   step, it may consume more memory than some similar functions such as
>   mysqli_fetch_array(), which only returns one row at a time from the
>   result set. **Further, if you need to iterate over the result set, you
>   will need a looping construct that will further impact performance.**
>   For these reasons mysqli_fetch_all() should only be used in those
>   situations where the fetched result set will be sent to another layer
>   for processing.

the part in bold implies that if he is doing some processing after each fetch_assoc:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

     $rows[] = $row;
     ... //im doing stuff with $row here

}
```

he could get better performance than using the mysqli_fetch_all function(which would have to loop through to get all rows), and then doing another loop for processing each row.

as far as some other speed analysis this blog post -> http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/2007/php-mysqli_fetch_all/ is a bit dated (2007) but does an ok job of comparing the two methods.